# Adding Javascript to ASPX page with C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have some Javascript code and I want to add it to my page in Default.aspx.cs.

I tried the following:

```
string sb = @" <script type='text/javascript'>
        var chart;

        var chartData = [{'year': 2005,'income': 23.5,'expenses': 18.1},
            {'year': 2006,'income': 26.2,'expenses': 22.8},
            {'year': 2007, 'income': 30.1, 'expenses': 23.9 },
            {'year': 2008,'income': 29.5,'expenses': 25.1},
            {'year': 2009,'income': 24.6,'expenses': 25}
            ];  
            AmCharts.ready(function () {
            chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
            chart.dataProvider = chartData;
            chart.categoryField = 'year';
            chart.startDuration = 1;
            chart.plotAreaBorderColor = '#DADADA';
            chart.plotAreaBorderAlpha = 1;chart.rotate = true;var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
            categoryAxis.gridPosition = 'start';
            categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;
            categoryAxis.axisAlpha = 0;var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
            valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
            valueAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;
            valueAxis.position = 'top';
            chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);
            var graph1 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph1.type = 'column';
            graph1.title = 'Income';
            graph1.valueField = 'income';
            graph1.balloonText = 'Income:[[value]]';
            graph1.lineAlpha = 0;
            graph1.fillColors = '#ADD981';
            graph1.fillAlphas = 1;
            chart.addGraph(graph1);
            var graph2 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph2.type = 'column';
            graph2.title = 'Expenses';
            graph2.valueField = 'expenses';
            graph2.balloonText = 'Expenses:[[value]]';
            graph2.lineAlpha = 0;
            graph2.fillColors = '#81acd9';
            graph2.fillAlphas = 1;
            chart.addGraph(graph2);var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
            chart.addLegend(legend); chart.creditsPosition = 'top-right';
            chart.write('chartdiv');
        });
    </script>";


        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page,
          this.GetType(), "MyFun1", sb, false);
```

The code works when directly added to the aspx page, but when I try this and try any other code I can't run it on my page.

I will fill values from database . So it must be dynamically

**edit:** I solved the problem. I added a label on page and wrote this code

```
        Label5.Text = sb;
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `<br>` tag next to `<script type='text/javascript'>`?

Comment: " tried any other codes but i can't run it on my page" - what does this mean?

Comment: i added <br> code for trying sth. I delete it but nothing changes. "tried any other codes " my English is not good . Sorry about it i mean i find and try some codes but they didn't work.

Comment: Because this is a jquery chart and i want to get values dynamically . year , income and expenses values will fill from database

Comment: Why you can't keep js in separete file and just add reference to it in your aspx file?

Comment: @sylwester how can i will change values dynamically . So i want to show script with string

Comment: Can you please clarify this: `The code works when directly added to the aspx page, but when I try this` - what do you mean by "when I try this" ?

Comment: Please read up on the StringBuilder and why you want to use it!

Comment: @Ender Ariç you can pass data to js via: 1)hidden input or 2) your js can call webservice to get data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the code has comments. It makes some of the javascript code invalid when render to browser, so remove those comments and try again.

For debugging, you can try render the script to **Literal** control first, and see any script error in Console.

```
string sb = @" <script type='text/javascript'>
    var chart;
    var chartData = [{ 'year': 2005, 'income': 23.5,'expenses': 18.1},
    AmCharts.ready(function () {
        chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart(); 
        chart.dataProvider = chartData;                
        chart.categoryField = 'year'; 
        chart.startDuration = 1; 
        chart.plotAreaBorderColor = '#DADADA'; 
        chart.plotAreaBorderAlpha = 1; 
        chart.rotate = true;
        var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;                
        categoryAxis.gridPosition = 'start';                
        categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;                
        categoryAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
        var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
        valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
        valueAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;
        valueAxis.position = 'top';
        chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);
        var graph1 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();                
        graph1.type = 'column';                
        graph1.title = 'Income';                
        graph1.valueField = 'income';                
        graph1.balloonText = 'Income:[[value]]';                
        graph1.lineAlpha = 0;                
        graph1.fillColors = '#ADD981';graph1.fillAlphas = 1;               
        chart.addGraph(graph1);
        var graph2 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();               
        graph2.type = 'column';                
        graph2.title = 'Expenses';                
        graph2.valueField = 'expenses';                
        graph2.balloonText = 'Expenses:[[value]]';                
        graph2.lineAlpha = 0;                
        graph2.fillColors = '#81acd9';               
        graph2.fillAlphas = 1;      
        chart.addGraph(graph2);
        var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();                
        chart.addLegend(legend);                
        chart.creditsPosition = 'top-right'; 
        chart.write('chartdiv');            
    });  
    </script>";


ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, 
  this.GetType(), "MyFun1", sb, false);
```

Comment: The `[` in the line `var chartData = [{ ` seems to miss the `]`. Does the browser's javascript console show any errors?

Comment: Did you try rending the above script to Literal control? Did you see any script error in Console?

Comment: thank you so much @Win i wrote your code into a label and it works :))